# NFT Sent to Smart Contract

Tags: contract-design, contract-invocation, erc-721, smart-contract-wallets

https://etherscan.io/address/0x23581767a106ae21c074b2276D25e5C3e136a68b#code

Had a pretty big oopsy. I know. No one is kicking myself more than me.

That being said, was curious if anyone saw a function in this contract that could potentially recover the lost assets. I see many transfer functions, but don't know if there are any that could recover my NFT!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can.
But that would have reverted if you would have used the `safeTransferFrom` function as this contract doesn't appear to implement the IERC721Receiver.

Did you used `safeTransfer` instead ?

Please check this: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L199

Comment: No it wasn't https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa5396dedf628fe0a1009605199f4c6ee053c2681f195035a261491338c48a537. But even better, the wallet (MetaMask/OpenSea?, a billion dollar company, the main beneficiary of ERC-721) should have easily detected this issue and made a loud warning.

Comment: Would make any difference if I had access to the contract creator, or is it stuck no matter what? 

Such a shame, seems like there were a lot of safeguards for this event that didn't kick in.

Comment: Wow that's insane, why didn't it have been fixed before ?